# Reading lines from a file and splitting them into arrays

Tags: c, linux, file

I am working on a Linux project in C. I am creating a number a processes and each one writes his information on a file in the following format

PID | NAME | TYPE | GENOME

and the process.txt file looks something like this:

- 567 | A | B | 20
- 568 | N | A | 2
- 569 | Z | B | 12

This information I provide while executing it's code. What i want to do is to let the parent process read the file at the end of the child execution and be able to split this values into arrays in this way:

```
    pids[] = {567, 568, 569}
    names[] = {A, N, Z}
    type[] = {B, A, B}
    genome[] = {20, 2, 12}
```

I have been looking for a way to do such thing but haven't found anything specific yet. A runnable code would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

I won't be helping you with your entire code, but here's a tip.

Read each line and then use `sscanf`to read the values into your arrays.

Here's a small code:

```
char name;
char type;
int pid;
int genome;

sscanf(line, "%d %c %c %d", &pid, &name, &type, &genome);
```

Answer (score 0):

When scan or writting a file, you need to open it first.
Then, you could specify what you want to do using **fprintf** to write or **fscanf** to scan the data.
To scan you file, here's the code :

```
int main(){
        char name[4], type[4];
        int pids[4], genome[4];
        int i = 0;
        FILE * file = fopen("process.txt", "r"); // "r" = read 
        while(fscanf(file, "%d|%c|%c|%d\n", &pids[i], name[i], type[i], &genome[i]) != EOF){
            i++;
        }
}
```

Comment: This snipper works perfectly with the example I showed before, but when I obtain as an output the file I work on it doesn't do anything.                    Here are the values of the file:                                                                 
           2309 | S | A | 5
          2310 | J | B | 2
          2311 | A | A | 4
          2312 | U | B | 6
          2313 | L | A | 3
          2314 | C | B | 5
          2315 | T | A | 2
          2316 | K | B | 4
          2317 | B | A | 6
          2318 | S | B | 3